# SQL MAX want to get only one value

Tags: sql-server

I just want to get one value, the maximum one, but after I add p.Name, this MAX won't work.

```
SELECT 
    p.Name, MAX(r.TaxRate) AS TaxRate
FROM 
    Sales.SalesTaxRate r
JOIN 
    Person.StateProvince p ON r.StateProvinceID = p.StateProvinceID
JOIN 
    Person.CountryRegion c ON c.CountryRegionCode = p.CountryRegionCode
WHERE 
    c.Name = 'Canada'
GROUP BY 
    p.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `RANK`:

```
SELECT
    Name, TaxRate
FROM(
    SELECT 
        p.Name, 
        r.TaxRate,
        rn = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY r.TaxRate DESC)
    FROM Sales.SalesTaxRate r
    JOIN Person.StateProvince p
        ON r.StateProvinceID = p.StateProvinceID
    JOIN Person.CountryRegion c
        ON c.CountryRegionCode = p.CountryRegionCode
    WHERE
        c.Name = 'Canada'
)t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Using `TOP WITH TIES`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    p.Name, 
    r.TaxRate
FROM Sales.SalesTaxRate r
JOIN Person.StateProvince p
    ON r.StateProvinceID = p.StateProvinceID
JOIN Person.CountryRegion c
    ON c.CountryRegionCode = p.CountryRegionCode
WHERE
    c.Name = 'Canada'
ORDER BY r.TaxRate DESC
```

Comment: this works! but if the highest tax rate are two with the same value. Should I change row number to 2 or something else?